# If I install windows server 2019 (iso file) on my computer will all my files get wiped?

Tags: iso-image, windows-server-2019

I mean, when I upgraded my account to 'Education', my data wasn't affected and nothing changed.

But that was just with a product key (without an .iso file)...

Comment: Reinstalling Windows will wipe your C: drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no upgrade path from Education to Server 2019, without that, you will lose all data when installed.